# What is the error in my exception and the throw and getMessage?

Tags: java, exception, getmessage

I have code and i want to know where is the error, please can you help me: only one error on the throw line

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number ");
        int x1 = input.nextInt();
        int i;
        if (x1>=0&&x1<=100) {
            i= (int) Math.pow(x1,2);
            System.out.println("the squre of  "+ x1 + " is "+ i);
        }
        else 
            throw new MyException();   // what is the error here?
    } catch(MyException me) {
        System.out.println(me);
        String message = me.getMessage();
    }
}

public class MyException extends Exception {
 public String getMessage() {
        return " the number is out of ring";
    }
    }

}
```

Comment: Is this your actual code? Your throw/catch statement looks wrong. Can you clean up the post please!

Comment: The compiler will tell you *exactly* where the error is.

Comment: What did the compiler say the error was?  By the way, I do _not_ get an error on `throw new MyException()`.

Comment: I've tried to clean up the post so others can understand it.  Obviously there's a `}` where it doesn't belong after `MyException`.  I do not know why you're getting an error on the `throw`, since I don't get one; you will need to tell us what the compiler says the error is.

Comment: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: OK, now I see why you're getting the error.

Comment: @Victor2748 sorry for stepping on your edit, I've tried to recreate it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your getMessage method is outside of you MyException class. Secondly, you are trying to call a method called getMessage(), which cannot be done in the main method, you have to call me.getMessage();

Comment: thank you i edit it . put i still have an error on the throw line

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you haven't quite posted your entire class, but based on the error message it looks like `MyException` occurs *inside* your class, something like:

```
public class TheClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ....
    }

    public class MyException extends Exception {
        ....
    }

}
```

This makes `MyException` an *inner* class.  Every instance of `MyException` must therefore "belong" to an instance of `TheClass`.  That's why you get the "non-static variable this" error message.  When you say `new MyException`, you're inside the static `main` method, so it has no way of knowing what instance of `TheClass` the new `MyException` object will belong to.

I don't think you want this to be an inner class.  Either move `MyException` *outside* of `TheClass`, or make it static:

```
public static class MyException extends Exception {
```

Making it static would make it a "nested" rather than an "inner" class, so that it doesn't belong to an instance of `TheClass`.  You probably want to move it outside, though.  I don't see a good reason for it to be in your other class.

Comment: i still have one error on the throw line

Comment: What change did you make, and is it the same error or a different one?  **Please do not just tell us on StackOverflow that the compiler is giving you an error, without telling us what it is.  Don't hide information from us.**

Comment: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: @GhadaAliOthman Did you make either of the changes I suggested in my answer?  If so, which one?

Comment: on the throw line .. i edit my post

Comment: public class MyException extends Exception {
 public String getMessage() {
        return " the number is out of ring";
    }
    }

Comment: @GhadaAliOthman I suggested either making `MyException` static or moving it outside your main class.  Did you make either of those changes?